# how to set xAxis label to show dates with interval of 1 day or week using charts? Also issue when showing yAxis value

Tags: ios, swift, charts

My code for bar chart is shown below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        IBviewGarph.delegate = self

        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [1200.0, 1400.0, 600.0, 3500.0, 1200.0, 1600.0, 1400.0, 1800.0, 1200.0, 1400.0, 1500.0, 1400.0]

        setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
    }
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        IBviewGarph.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 500
        IBviewGarph.leftAxis.axisMaxValue = 3500

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)

        IBviewGarph.data = chartData
        IBviewGarph.descriptionText = ""
        chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)]
        IBviewGarph.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
        IBviewGarph.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        IBviewGarph.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

    }
```

issue is as you can see image , yAxis is showing 2 lines , dont know what is issue and also i want to set xAxis labels to show dates Ex: "28/8/2016" with interval of 1 day or 1 week , how to pass custom labels to xAxis same as i have done for yAxis? May be similar question :[Chart - Controlling axis interval, spacing and visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341250/chart-controlling-axis-interval-spacing-and-visibility?rq=1) but dont know work around for my question as i have just simply put numbers   [image]

Comment: I have solved my 1 issue which is yAxis multiple line showing in graph. there is property `forceLabelsEnabled` Needs to set it true so that those lines will be calculated according to min and max..