# How can i create empty new windows forms chart without any graph/s in it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 designer i have windows forms Chart control.
Then in form1 top:

```
ChartArea area;
```

Then a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            area = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10,10);
            area.AxisX.Minimum = 1;
            area.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
            area.AxisY.Minimum = 1;
            area.AxisY.Maximum = 120;
        }
```

When i click the button i'm getting:

[image: Chart]

I want a new clean chart with the squares and the values of the axis y and x but only without the blue Series1 on the bottom.

If i change this line chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10,10); and make instead 10,10 for example 0,0 the whole graph is not complete.
But i want just without the blue Series1

I didn't understand why and where it's adding this Series1 and why at this location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 Chart control, how to display a blank chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199297/vs2010-chart-control-how-to-display-a-blank-chart)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var area = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        area.AxisX.Minimum = 1;
        area.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
        area.AxisY.Minimum = 1;
        area.AxisY.Maximum = 120;
```

Is that what you are looking for visually?