# MSchart chart area become invisible when Series[0] disabled

Tags: winforms, mschart

chart1 includes 4 Series in same chart area, X and Y axis. The problem is this, when I make:

```
chart1.Series[0].Enabled=false;
chart1.Series[1].Enabled=true;
chart1.Series[3].Enabled=true;
chart1.Series[2].Enabled=true;
```

Only legend is become visible on the chart with three series on it.

But if

```
 chart1.Series[0].Enabled=true;
```

chart1.Series[1], chart1.Series[2],chart1.Series[3] can be enabled/disabled without any problem.

Where can the problem is?

Comment: Whats the problem?  If you Enable/Disable a series it shows/hides it from the chart completely, on both the chart and the legend.  Are you saying that if you set Enabled to false on Series 2 it still shows up?  What is your Series ChartType?

Comment: The problem was this, if I make disabled Series[0] chart was becoming invisible.  But if I make Series [1] disabled for example there is no problem. I found it, only Series[0] was have points in it. So when chart area haven't got any point on it, it becomes invisible. The another solution is make point border width zero instead of making series disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2010 Chart control, how to display a blank chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199297/vs2010-chart-control-how-to-display-a-blank-chart)

Comment: At least one DataPoint must be showing or else the Chartarea won't show. The point can be a transparent dummy.